# Garage door seal is glued and I want to replace it

Tags: garage-door, seal

My garage door doesn't seem to have the plate that you see in new doors these days where you can slide the rubber seal. Mine is hard glued at the bottom and side of the door. Does anyone know a way to removing this glued seal and installing a new plate that allows me to slide the seal instead? I don't want to glue a new one on.

Answer (score 1):

Overhead door seal channels are available as well as the rubber seals. Kits would probably come with sheet metal screws for mounting. You'd just need to pull the old seal off or cut it away so that it gets covered.

[image]